# I Want to do Chrome browser history delete programmatically.Is any one do same earlier?

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser

Hello Actually i want to clean browser history(Chrome Browser)with user permission but

```
Browser.clearHistory(cR);
```

this is only for default browser of mobile device not a Chrome always i.e. working is not proper going because many of people only use Chrome as a browsing in android so any one please help me to delete Chrome browser history

Comment: refer this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366128/clear-android-browser-history

Comment: no, they clean default i want to clean chrome browser history